# Sharepoint 2010 Discussion Board Thread.xsl

Tags: xslt, discussion-board

Ok, I have searched and searched for an answer on how to customize the thread.xsl file.  So I have copied the file, and renamed it as thread2.xsl.  In the threaded.aspx page, I have changed the GhostedXslLink to reference the new file GhostedXslLink="thread2.xsl".  I have save the page, I can see my changes reflected within SPD, but the browser still shows me the old template.  Any Ideas Why??

Update:
Here's the code:

```
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" Description="Use the Team Discussion list to hold newsgroup-style discussions on topics relevant to your team." ListDisplayName="" PartOrder="2" Default="TRUE" HelpLink="" AllowRemove="True" IsVisible="True" AllowHide="True" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" ExportControlledProperties="False" IsIncludedFilter="" DataSourceID="" Title="Team Discussion" ViewFlag="402653185" NoDefaultStyle="" AllowConnect="True" DisplayName="Threaded" PageType="PAGE_DEFAULTVIEW" FrameState="Normal" PageSize="-1" PartImageLarge="" AsyncRefresh="False" ExportMode="NonSensitiveData" Dir="Default" DetailLink="/Lists/Team Discussion" EnableTheming="False" ShowWithSampleData="False" ListId="eb26c71f-c466-411d-a9ae-7372a657b18e" ListName="{EB26C71F-C466-411D-A9AE-7372A657B18E}" FrameType="Default" PartImageSmall="" IsIncluded="True" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" AllowEdit="True" ViewGuid="{0B1EA108-E3E5-46E5-8813-E747175FF805}" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" AllowMinimize="True" WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ViewContentTypeId="0x0120020061C489FDBE1EA34DB10A6609E7D509AE" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" GhostedXslLink="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." HelpMode="Modeless" ListUrl="" ID="g_0b1ea108_e3e5_46e5_8813_e747175ff805" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" AllowZoneChange="True" TitleUrl="/Lists/Team Discussion" ManualRefresh="False" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{0B1EA108-E3E5-46E5-8813-E747175FF805}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" WebPart="true" Height="" Width="" __designer:customxsl="fldtypes_Ratings.xsl"><ParameterBindings>
        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/>
        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
        <ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" />
        <ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" />
        <ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" />
        <ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" />
        <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_discboard)" />
        <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_discboard_howto3)" />
        <ParameterBinding Name="CAML_Expand" Location="Form(CAML_Expand)" />
        <ParameterBinding Name="CAML_ShowOriginalEmailBody" Location="Form(CAML_ShowOriginalEmailBody)" />
        <ParameterBinding Name="ByText" Location="Resource(wss,2000)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
    <XmlDefinition>
        <View Name="{0B1EA108-E3E5-46E5-8813-E747175FF805}" DefaultView="TRUE" DefaultViewForContentType="TRUE" Type="HTML" TabularView="FALSE" IncludeRootFolder="TRUE" DisplayName="Threaded" Url="/Lists/Team Discussion/Threaded.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x0120020061C489FDBE1EA34DB10A6609E7D509AE" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/vwdisc.png" CssStyleSheet="discthread.css">
            <Query>
                <OrderBy Override="TRUE">
                    <FieldRef Name="Threading"/>
                </OrderBy>
            </Query>
            <ViewFields>
                <FieldRef Name="Threading"/>
            </ViewFields>
            <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">25</RowLimit>
            <Aggregations Value="Off"/>
            <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
        </View>
    </XmlDefinition>
    <XslLink>/Style%20Library/XSL%20Style%20Sheets/thread2.xsl</XslLink>
            <DataFields>
            </DataFields>
            </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
```

Here is the error that I get:

> 06/13/2012 13:59:53.78 w3wp.exe (0x1DB4)                                       0x1F44  SharePoint Foundation                 Web Parts                                     89a1       High       Error while executing web part: System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: An item of type 'Attribute' cannot be constructed within a node of type 'Root'.     at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryOutput.ThrowInvalidStateError(XPathNodeType constructorType)     at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryOutput.WriteStartAttribute(String prefix, String localName, String ns)     at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryOutput.WriteStartAttributeLocalName(String localName)     at (XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime, XPathNavigator {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}current)     at (XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)     at Ro...    877aac16-ef57-4be7-9035-029f71c7b215

Comment: Based on the error message you've posted, the problem is inside your XSLT. This means your customized XSLT file is applied, so I assume the initial problem is solved. I would appreciate if you posted the customization XSLT code and the complete call stack (error message above doesn't include *full* call stack) in a separate question.

Answer (score 5):

When you change a page in SPD, it becomes customized (unghosted). Thus, `GhostedXslLink` no longer works.

More details about ghosted and unghosted pages here:

- http://www.etechplanet.com/blog/ghosted-and-unghosted-pages-in-sharepoint.aspx

You should use `XslLink` property instead of `GhostedXslLink` for unghosted pages. Just change it in the property editor in SPD:

[image]

Also, I'd recommend you to use [xsl:import](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_import.asp) rather than copying the whole **thread.xsl** file.

**Update**:

I was able to attach custom XSLT file to a Discussion board without any difficulties in my local environment. Here is how I've done it (in case this could help you):

1. copy-pasted thread.xsl to thread2.xsl
2. added html code `<h1>test!</h1>` to EmptyTemplate of this file, inside `<td>` element (full code snippet below)
3. created blank new discussion board list
4. switched page into edit mode and opened webpart properties for the list view webpart
5. in webpart properties tab, entered "/_layouts/XSL/thread2.xsl" to Miscellaneous => XSL Link (which produces exactly the same result as changing XslLink property in SPD)
6. applied changes

The result:

[image]

XSLT code for the EmptyTemplate:

```
  <xsl:template name="EmptyTemplate">
    <tr>
      <td class="ms-vb" colspan="99">
        <xsl:value-of select="$NoAnnouncements"/>
        <xsl:if test="$ListRight_AddListItems = '1'">
          <xsl:if test="not (BaseViewID='1' or @BaseViewID='2')">
            <xsl:text ddwrt:whitespace-preserve="yes" xml:space="preserve"> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$NoAnnouncementsHowTo"/>
            <h1>test!</h1>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Ok, so I used the XslLink property and I have now gotten a broken webpart, it states "This Web Part does not have a valid XSLT stylesheet: There is no XSL property available for presenting the data"  I know that there is, the only thing that I have done is take out the Tables and replaced them with divs so i can control them better.

Comment: If I add the path /_layouts/xsl/thread2.xsl then the error goes away yet I still see the default threaded xsl view.

Comment: see code update above.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to reproduce your issue. My only guess: something is wrong with the XSL customization. Which template did you change and how? Please note: some templates in this file match specific BaseViewID-s (i.e. `match="Row[../../@BaseViewID='2']"` matches views with BaseViewID=2), so if you changed common template (i.e. `match=Row`), but the view has BaseViewID set to one of system values, the more specific template will be applied.

Comment: I've updated my answer with my steps, please consider following them so you could at least determine there the problem is. I mean, maybe your custom file is actually applied, but you placed your customization into a wrong template or smth like this :)

Comment: I am not editing the dvwp, I am trying to change the layout of the actual discussion.