# Discussion Board XSLT

Tags: xslt, discussion-board

first off, here is the post that goes with this one. [Sharepoint 2010 Discussion Board Thread.xsl](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38414/sharepoint-2010-discussion-board-thread-xsl)

Ok, I am trying to modify the ootb sharepoint discussion board xslt, with divs with id's so I can easily format it the way our designer wants them to look.  I am getting the error

> An item of type 'Attribute' cannot be constructed within a node of type 'Root'.

Here is the code:

```
          <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Editor.span" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </div>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="FieldRef_Thread_BodyAndMore_Computed_Thread" match="FieldRef[@Name='BodyAndMore']" mode="Computed_body" ddwrt:dvt_mode="body">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:param name="Position" select="1"/>
            <xsl:if test="$Position = 1">
          <input type="hidden" name="CAML_Expand" value="{$CAML_Expand}"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="CAML_ShowOriginalEmailBody" value="{$CAML_ShowOriginalEmailBody}"/>
        </xsl:if>
            <xsl:variable name="isRootPost">
                <xsl:call-template name="IsRootPost">
                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="$isRootPost='TRUE'">
          <div style="padding-bottom: 4px;">
            <b>
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@FSObjType='1'">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Title"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@DiscussionTitleLookup"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </b>
          </div>
        </xsl:if>
            <xsl:variable name="BodyPositioningClass">
                <xsl:if test="$isRootPost='TRUE'">ms-disc-root-body</xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>
        <div class="{$BodyPositioningClass}">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@Body=''">
              <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/../@resource.wss.NoText"/>
            </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:variable name="WasExpanded">
                        <xsl:call-template name="BodyWasExpanded">
                            <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select ="$thisNode"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
              </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$WasExpanded='TRUE'">
                  <!-- fullbody -->
                            <xsl:call-template name="FullBody">
                                <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                            <xsl:variable name="CorrectBody">
                                <xsl:call-template name="CorrectBodyToShow">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                  </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="contains($CorrectBody, 'TrimmedBody')">
                        <!--brent edit-->
                        <div id="trimmedBody">
                              <xsl:call-template name="LessLink">
                                <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select ="$thisNode"/>
                              </xsl:call-template>
                              <xsl:call-template name="ToggleQuotedText">
                                <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select ="$thisNode"/>
                              </xsl:call-template>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:call-template name="LessLink">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select ="$thisNode"/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:variable name="TextWasExpanded">
                                <xsl:call-template name="QuotedTextWasExpanded">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select ="$thisNode"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                  </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="$TextWasExpanded='TRUE'">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="FullBody">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                    <xsl:call-template name="ToggleQuotedText">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select ="$thisNode"/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:call-template name="LimitedBody">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select ="$thisNode"/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </div>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="FieldRef_Thread_Threading_Computed_Thread" match="FieldRef[@Name='Threading']" mode="Computed_body" ddwrt:dvt_mode="body">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:param name="Position" select="1"/>

        <!--Brent Edit-->
            <xsl:variable name="ID">
                <xsl:call-template name="ResolveId">
                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <div id="IndentTemplate{$ID}{generate-id()}">
                <xsl:call-template name="Indentation">
                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:call-template name="FieldRef_Thread_BodyAndMore_Computed_Thread">
                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="Position" select="$Position"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
        </div>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="LessLink">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
        <div id="LessMoreLink">
          <br />
          <a id="LessLink{$thisNode/@ID}" href="javascript:" onclick="javascript:return CollapseBody('{$thisNode/@GUID}','{$thisNode/@GUID}',this);">
            <img id="lessIcon" border="0" align="absmiddle" alt="{$thisNode/../@resource.wss.LessText}" src="/_layouts/images/dlmin.gif" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/../@resource.wss.LessText"/>
          </a>
        </div>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="FullBody">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:variable name="MessageBodyText">
                <xsl:call-template name="MessageBody">
                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@RichText='TRUE'">
            <xsl:value-of select="$MessageBodyText" disable-output-escaping ="yes"/>
          </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
            <!--todo: deal with autonewline stuffs.-->
            <xsl:value-of select="$MessageBodyText" disable-output-escaping ="yes"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="ToggleQuotedText">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:variable name="CorrectBody">
                <xsl:call-template name="CorrectBodyToShow">
                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="CorrectBody">
                <xsl:call-template name="CorrectBodyToShow">
                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="MessageBody">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:variable name="CorrectBody">
                <xsl:call-template name="CorrectBodyToShow">
                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$CorrectBody='TrimmedBody'">
            <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@TrimmedBody"/>
          </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Body"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="LimitedBody">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:variable name="MessageBodyText">
                <xsl:call-template name="MessageBody">
                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
            </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="MoreLink">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
        <div id="moreTextLink"><br />
          <a id="MoreLink{$thisNode/@ID}" href="javascript:" onclick="javascript:return ExpandBody('{$thisNode/@GUID}'','{$thisNode/@GUID}',this);">
            <span style="height:13px;width:13px;position:relative;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;" class="s4-clust"><img src="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png" alt="{$thisNode/../@resource.wss.MoreText}" style="left:-0px !important;top:-238px !important;position:absolute;" id="moreIcon" border="0" align="absmiddle" /></span><xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/../@resource.wss.ShowQuotedMessages"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/../@resource.wss.MoreText"/>
          </a>
        </div>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="BodyWasExpanded">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$CAML_Expand and contains($CAML_Expand, $thisNode/@GUID)">TRUE</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>FALSE</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="QuotedTextWasExpanded">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$CAML_ShowOriginalEmailBody and contains($CAML_ShowOriginalEmailBody, $thisNode/@GUID)">TRUE</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>FALSE</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="CorrectBodyToShow">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:variable name="WasExpanded">
                <xsl:call-template name="QuotedTextWasExpanded">
                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select ="$thisNode"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$WasExpanded='TRUE'">UnTrimmedBody</xsl:when >
                <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- If we have an unedited item with a TrimmedBody, show that. Otherwise, show Body.-->
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@Created. =$thisNode/@Modified.">
                            <xsl:variable name="isRootPost">
                                <xsl:call-template name="IsRootPost">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="$isRootPost='TRUE'">BODY</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@TrimmedBody=''">BODY</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>TrimmedBody</xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>Body</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="IsRootPost">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:variable name="V_ShortestThreadIndexId">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@FSObjType = '1'">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@ShortestThreadIndexId='0'">
                <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@ID"/>
              </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@ShortestThreadIndexId"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@ShortestThreadIndexIdLookup"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$V_ShortestThreadIndexId=''">
                    <xsl:variable name="indentLevel">
                        <xsl:call-template name="IndentLevel">
                            <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$indentLevel=0">TRUE</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>FALSE</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$V_ShortestThreadIndexId=$thisNode/@ID">TRUE</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>FALSE</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="IndentLevel">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="floor(string-length($thisNode/@ThreadIndex) div 10) - 4"/>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="Indentation">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
        <img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width="{string-length($thisNode/@ThreadIndex) - 46}px" height="1px" alt="" />
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="IndentStatusBar">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
        <!--Brent Edit-->
        <div id="statusBarIndent{generate-id()}">
              <xsl:call-template name="Indentation">
                <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>            
              </xsl:call-template>
              <xsl:call-template name="StatusBar">
                <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
              </xsl:call-template>
        </div>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='ReplyNoGif']" mode="Computed_body" ddwrt:dvt_mode="body">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:call-template name="ReplyNoGif">
                <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select ="$thisNode"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="FieldRef_Thread_StatusBar_Computed_body" match="FieldRef[@Name='StatusBar']" mode="Computed_body" ddwrt:dvt_mode="body">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:call-template name="StatusBar">
                <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="0"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="StatusBar">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:param name="indent" select="1"/>
            <xsl:variable name="indentLevel">
                <xsl:call-template name="IndentLevel">
                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
              <div id="mainContainer{generate-id()}">
                <a name="{$thisNode/@GUID}"></a>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:call-template name="IfHasRight">
                        <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:choose>
              </div >
            <xsl:if test="$Collapse">
                <xsl:attribute name="style">display:none</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <div id="linkDisplay{generate-id()}"><a id="DisplayLink{$thisNode/@ID}" href="{$FORM_DISPLAY}&amp;ID={$thisNode/@ID}" onclick="EditLink2(this,{$ViewCounter});return false;" target="_self"><nobr><xsl:value-of select="'View Properties'" /></nobr></a></div>
            <xsl:variable name="hasRight">
                <xsl:call-template name="IfHasRight">
                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="$hasRight"><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" alt="" /><div id="buttonReply{generate-id()}">
                <xsl:call-template name="ReplyNoGif">
                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode" />
                </xsl:call-template>
                </div>
            </xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="ReplyNoGif">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
        <a id="ReplyLink{$thisNode/@ID}" href="{$ENCODED_FORM_NEW}&amp;ContentTypeId=0x0107&amp;DiscussionParentID={$thisNode/@ID}" onclick="EditLink2(this,{$ViewCounter});return false;" target="_self">
          <img id="replyButton{generate-id()}" border="0" align="middle" alt="{$thisNode/../@resource.wss.ReplyLinkText}" src="/_layouts/images/reply.gif" />
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>

          <nobr><b>
            <xsl:value-of select="'Reply'"/>
          </b></nobr>
        </a>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template mode="Item" match="Row[../../@BaseViewID='1']">
            <xsl:param name="Fields" select="."/>
            <xsl:param name="Collapse" select="."/>
            <xsl:param name="Position" select="1" />
            <xsl:variable name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$Fields">
                <xsl:if test="$Collapse">
                    <xsl:attribute name="style">display:none</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
                <xsl:call-template name="IndentStatusBar">
                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:if test="$Collapse">
                    <xsl:attribute name="style">display:none</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="position()=1">ms-disc-bordered</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>ms-disc-bordered-noleft</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:if test="@Name='Threading'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="width">100%</xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:apply-templates mode="PrintFieldWithDisplayFormLink" select=".">
                <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="Position" select="$Position"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template mode="Item" match="Row[../../@BaseViewID='2']">
            <xsl:param name="Fields" select="."/>
            <xsl:param name="Collapse" select="."/>
            <xsl:param name="Position" select="1" />
            <xsl:variable name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="$Collapse">
                <xsl:attribute name="style">display:none</xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position()=1">ms-disc-padabove</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>ms-disc-nopad</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="$XmlDefinition/ViewFields/FieldRef[@Name='StatusBar']">
              <xsl:apply-templates mode="PrintFieldWithDisplayFormLink" select=".">
                <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="Position" select="$Position"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:if test="$Collapse">
                <xsl:attribute name="style">display:none</xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
            <xsl:for-each select="$Fields">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="position()=1">ms-disc-bordered</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>ms-disc-bordered-noleft</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:if test="@Name='BodyAndMore'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="width">100%</xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:apply-templates mode="PrintFieldWithDisplayFormLink" select=".">
                <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="Position" select="$Position"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:if test="$Collapse">
                <xsl:attribute name="style">display:none</xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
            <img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width="1px" height="15px" alt=""/>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="FieldRef_Thread_UserBody" match="FieldRef" mode="User_body" ddwrt:dvt_mode="body">
            <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$XmlDefinition/@BaseViewID='1' or $XmlDefinition/@BaseViewID='2'">
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$thisNode/@*[name()=concat(current()/@Name, '.span')]" />
          </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="View_Thread_Summary_RootTemplate" match="View[List/@TemplateType='108' and @BaseViewID='0']" mode="RootTemplate" ddwrt:dvt_mode="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="full" />
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="View_Thread_Default_RootTemplate" match="View[List/@TemplateType='108']" mode="RootTemplate" ddwrt:dvt_mode="root" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">
            <xsl:call-template name="CTXGeneration"/>
              <xsl:if test="not($NoAJAX)">
                <iframe src="javascript:false;" id="FilterIframe{$ViewCounter}" name="FilterIframe{$ViewCounter}" style="display:none" height="0" width="0" FilterLink="{$FilterLink}"></iframe>
              </xsl:if>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:choose><!-- Any time we display 0 items in a view = class="ms-viewEmpty" -->
                    <xsl:when test="$dvt_RowCount = 0">ms-viewEmpty</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:choose><!-- Threaded/Flat view with non-zero number of items = class="ms-disc" -->
                            <xsl:when test="(@BaseViewID='1' or @BaseViewID='2')">ms-disc</xsl:when>
                            <!-- Subject view with non-zero number of items = class="ms-listviewtable" -->
                            <xsl:otherwise>ms-listviewtable</xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="full" />
            <xsl:call-template name="pagingButtons" />
            <xsl:if test="Toolbar[@Type='Freeform'] or ($MasterVersion=4 and Toolbar[@Type='Standard'])">
                    <xsl:call-template name="Freeform">
                        <xsl:with-param name="AddNewText">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="List/@TemplateType='108'"><xsl:value-of select="'Add new discussion'" /></xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="'Add new item'" /></xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="ID">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="List/@TemplateType='108'">idHomePageNewDiscussion</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>idHomePageNewItem</xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="EmptyTemplate">
            <xsl:value-of select="$NoAnnouncements"/>
            <xsl:if test="$ListRight_AddListItems = '1'">
                <xsl:if test="not (BaseViewID='1' or @BaseViewID='2')">
                    <xsl:text ddwrt:whitespace-preserve="yes" xml:space="preserve"> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$NoAnnouncementsHowTo"/>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Could you post the full call trace from ULS, which goes with the error message? There should be information about from which template the error was raised.

Comment: it is in this post http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38414/sharepoint-2010-discussion-board-thread-xsl

Answer (score 3):

Inside your RootTemplate (`name="View_Thread_Default_RootTemplate"`), you have `<xsl:attribute name="class">`, but you cannot use **xsl:attribute** without a parent tag. That is what causes the error.

To fix it, you should either remove the `<xsl:attribute>` tag, or wrap it to some HTML tag (i.e. `<div>`).

After wrapping to `<div>`, the error dissapears and I was able to get the following resulting view of the discussion board (using your XSLT):

[image]

The final code for the RootTemplate:

```
  <xsl:template name="View_Thread_Default_RootTemplate" match="View[List/@TemplateType='108']" mode="RootTemplate" ddwrt:dvt_mode="root" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">
    <xsl:call-template name="CTXGeneration"/>
    <xsl:if test="not($NoAJAX)">
      <iframe src="javascript:false;" id="FilterIframe{$ViewCounter}" name="FilterIframe{$ViewCounter}" style="display:none" height="0" width="0" FilterLink="{$FilterLink}"></iframe>
    </xsl:if>
    <div>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:choose>
          <!-- Any time we display 0 items in a view = class="ms-viewEmpty" -->
          <xsl:when test="$dvt_RowCount = 0">ms-viewEmpty</xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:choose>
              <!-- Threaded/Flat view with non-zero number of items = class="ms-disc" -->
              <xsl:when test="(@BaseViewID='1' or @BaseViewID='2')">ms-disc</xsl:when>
              <!-- Subject view with non-zero number of items = class="ms-listviewtable" -->
              <xsl:otherwise>ms-listviewtable</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="full" />
      <xsl:call-template name="pagingButtons" />
      <xsl:if test="Toolbar[@Type='Freeform'] or ($MasterVersion=4 and Toolbar[@Type='Standard'])">
        <xsl:call-template name="Freeform">
          <xsl:with-param name="AddNewText">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="List/@TemplateType='108'">
                <xsl:value-of select="'Add new discussion'" />
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="'Add new item'" />
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:with-param>
          <xsl:with-param name="ID">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="List/@TemplateType='108'">idHomePageNewDiscussion</xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>idHomePageNewItem</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116070/sharepoint-2013-modify-discussion-board-view-layout-style can you help me please ?