# SharePoint 2013 Modify discussion Board View layout style

Tags: list-view, discussion-board

I  have been searching for a while now on how can i modify the Discussion board look'n feel.

My client wants to have the discussion functionnality on his site, but he wants to change significantly the look'n feel of the Discussion obviously the layouts and style of the view ...

I was wondering if there is any way to do this since i am using a list based on discussion board template created from Visual studio...

any help will be appreciated ...